# Как продлить сертификат Let-s-Encrypt?

Tags: nginx, https, ssl, letsencrypt

Три месяца назад сделал для сайта `Let-s-Encrypt` сертификат.
Делал [по этой инструкции](https://community.vscale.io/hc/ru/community/posts/208332509-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-SSL-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-Nginx-%D1%81-Let-s-Encrypt-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-Ubuntu-16-04). Использую `nginx` + `debian`.

Сейчас при комманде `renew` получаю ошибку:

> Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/examenpdd.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. examenpdd.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://examenpdd.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/DvvnMOW82Rlm1D7t7kAnL9XpzKHypqeGQaFWURPZtSQ:

Конфигурацию `nginx` вроде не менял. Вот мой [конфиг](https://gist.github.com/mezhevikin/8c80159e021355abffafd0b1f04bd79c)

Буду рад любым идеям по устранению проблемы.

Comment: Вы сами-то пробовали по этой ссылке перейти?

Comment: Смотрите логи `nginx`

Comment: я понимаю что проблема в том что нет доступа к файлы. Вопрос как это устранить?

Comment: @nullproduction убрать из конфига `deny all`, очевидно же :)

Comment: Но `location ~ /\.ht {deny all;}` лучше всё-таки оставить))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

убедитесь, что в конфигурации программы *nginx* для данного сайта есть директива `location` для запроса `.well-known/acme-challenge`, что ведёт она к существующему каталогу, и что этот каталог доступен для чтения пользователю, от имени которого *nginx* обслуживает данный сайт.

проинспектировать принадлежность и права всех каталогов в пути удобно с помощью программы *namei*. например:

```
$ namei -l /etc/nginx/sites-available/
f: /etc/nginx/sites-available/
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root etc
drwxr-xr-x root root nginx
drwxr-xr-x root root sites-available
```

если проверяемый пользователь, например, `www-data`, то инспекцию можно сделать так:

```
$ sudo -u www-data namei -l /etc/nginx/sites-available/
```

ответ будет тем же самым. а вот для недоступного каталога:

```
$ sudo -u www-data namei -l /root/.ssh/id_rsa
f: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwx------ root root root
                     .ssh - No such file or directory
```

видно, что внутрь каталога `/root` пользователь уже не смог «заглянуть»: недостаточно прав.

#### дополнение про логику проверки принадлежности домена:

клиент, которым вы запускаете процедуру обновления, во-первых, должен знать, где находится каталог `acme-challenge` (для данного сайта), доступный по адресу `http://ваш.домен/.well-known/acme-challenge`, во-вторых, должен иметь право записи в этот каталог: во время процедуры обновления он создаёт в нём файл с именем и содержимым, переданным сервером *letsencrypt*, а тот после этого пытается прочитать этот файл. по завершении процедуры клиент удаляет этот файл.

потому, при обслуживании нескольких доменов на одной машине, имеет смысл сделать один каталог для проверки, который и указать в клиенте, а в конфигурации *nginx* описать его (для каждой секции `server`) примерно так:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  alias /путь/к/этому/каталогу;
}
```

эту секцию имеет смысл помещать в секцию `server`, слушающую 80-й порт, чтобы не было лишних перенаправлений на https (который может и не работать на момент получения (нового) сертификата).

клиент должен иметь права для записи в этот каталог, а пользователю(-ям), от имени которых обслуживается сайт(-ы) — достаточно права чтения.

Comment: В данном случае просто конфиг nginx неправильный, приоритет deny оказался выше приоритета allow

Comment: alexander barakin спасибо за ответ. @andreymal ваше предположение оказалось неверным. Проблема была в том что сайт изначально лежал в папке /var/www/html потом я перенес его в другую папку, сейчач вернул как было и все продлилось, видимо где-то изначальный путь захаркорен

Comment: @nullproduction моё предположение оказалось верным, потому что минут 20-30 назад ошибка 403 заменилась на ошибку 404 и вместе с `/.well-known/` также стал доступен `.htaccess` — очевидно, вы на время убрали `deny all` из конфига и потом вернули обратно.

Comment: я конечно пробовал то что вы советовали, это не помогло, я вернул обратно, вспомнил про переименование папки и после этого уже продлил.

Comment: @nullproduction значит дело было *не только* в этом. Но то, что дело было *в том числе* и в этом тоже, я гарантирую

Comment: Сейчас у вас `/.well-known` опять недоступен (403) и следующее продление тоже не сработает

Comment: @nullproduction, дополнил ответ.